# BASH extract links from youtube html file

Tags: bash, youtube

Im trying to make youtube music player on my raspberry, and I've stuck on this moment:

Wget is downloading site for example: `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=test` to file output.html

Links in that site are saved in strings like that: `<a href="/watch?v=DDzfeTTigKo"`

Now when I am trying to grep them `cat site | grep -B 0 -A 0 watch?v=`

It prints me the wall of text from that file, and I just want that specific lines like i mention above. And i want it to be saved in file site2

Is this possible?

Comment: I recommend you to use an XML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with GNU grep:

```
grep -o '"/watch?v=[^"]*"' file.html
```